# Set users password in code?

Tags: users

I would like to be able to change a users password in code.

Since `user_load` returns an object, and `user_save` wants an array, this is non-trivial.

I assume someone has figured out a quick and easy way to do it.

---

My current solution looks like:

```
db_update('users')
  ->fields(array('pass' => user_hash_password('some_password')))
  ->condition('uid', 1)
  ->execute();
```

But I don't like that this bypasses most hooks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to call `user_save()` using code similar to the following one.

```
$edit['pass'] = 'New password';
user_save($account, $edit);
```

`$account` contains the user object for the user account to alter. I get you load it using `user_load()`, but it could also be the user object for the currently logged in user. In the latter case, Drupal will regenerate the session using the following code (part of [user_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7)).

```
  // If the password changed, delete all open sessions and recreate
  // the current one.
  if ($account->pass != $account->original->pass) {
    drupal_session_destroy_uid($account->uid);
    if ($account->uid == $GLOBALS['user']->uid) {
      drupal_session_regenerate();
    }
  }
```

The password in `$edit['pass']` is the plain password. `user_save()` will replace it with its hash using the following code (at the beginning of the function).

```
if (!empty($edit['pass'])) {
  // Allow alternate password hashing schemes.
  require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . variable_get('password_inc', 'includes/password.inc');
  $edit['pass'] = user_hash_password(trim($edit['pass']));
  // Abort if the hashing failed and returned FALSE.
  if (!$edit['pass']) {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

As alternative, you could use [drupal_submit_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_form_submit/7).

```
$form_state = array();
$form_state['user'] = $account;
$form_state['values']['pass']['pass1'] = 'New password';
$form_state['values']['pass']['pass2'] = 'New password';
$form_state['values']['op'] = t('Save');
drupal_form_submit('user_profile_form', $form_state);
```

In this way, if you have any module that, for example, validates the password, its code would be executed, and you would get any error code from [form_get_errors()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_get_errors/7).